# 'self is not defined' when buiding Server Side Rendering bundle

Tags: webpack, mapbox-gl-js, server-side-rendering

When ever I try to run the bundle build with webpack I'm getting this error.

```
NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: 
ReferenceError: <b>self is not defined</b>
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/<b>mapbox-gl.js:28:4972</b>)
```

I've tried adding the noParse: /(mapbox-gl).js$/ in webpack.config without success

Comment: Think you might need to provide more information about your setup, there's not a lot to go on there.